# ImportError: No module named twitter on shell file

Tags: python, shell, twitter

So i installed twitter with 
easy_install twitter

my_file.py

```
import twitter
......
......
```

When I run my python file directly on the terminal it works fine

```
>python my_file.py
```

However, when I put the above into a shell file

run_script.sh

```
python my_file.py
```

I run this file using

```
>sh run_script.sh
```

I get an error

```
ImportError: No module named 'twitter'
```

Why does it not recognise the imported module post installation when I try it through the shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a sha bang at the top of file like -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import twitter
Your code goes here ...
```

And then in terminal run this command to make this file executable

```
$ chmod +x my_file.py
```

and add this in bash script:-

```
./my_file.py
```

Also make sure you have installed the module globally rather than installing it in a virtualenv

Comment: ./my_file.py ..... when you say add this in bash script what exactly do you mean? are you saying add this in the run_script.sh file? what is the purpose of this line